# Select method of range class failed for selection

Tags: excel, vba

Hi i have recorded a macro and i want to implement it into my current vba macro, however upon testing the code with the button on another sheet, there seem to be an

> error 1004 which states Select method of range class failed

highlighting the selection part of the code." Sheets("Raw").Cells.Select " did i miss out anything in my code or is there any suggestion. Thanks in advance !

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
' unmerge Macro
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q

Sheets("Raw").Cells.Select
Selection.unmerge
    With Selection
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
        End With

    Sheets("Raw").Rows("1:5").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Sheets("Raw").Cells.Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 8.29
    Sheets("Raw").Range("C:C,E:F,H:H,J:M,O:R,T:T,V:W,Y:AA").Select
    Sheets("Raw").Range("Y1").Activate

    Sheets("Raw").Range( _
        "C:C,E:F,H:H,J:M,O:R,T:T,V:W,Y:AA,AC:AD,AF:AH,AJ:AJ,AL:AM,AO:AO,AQ:AR,AT:AU"). _
        Select
    Sheets("Raw").Range("AT1").Activate

    Sheets("Raw").Range( _
        "C:C,E:F,H:H,J:M,O:R,T:T,V:W,Y:AA,AC:AD,AF:AH,AJ:AJ,AL:AM,AO:AO,AQ:AR,AT:AU,AW:AY" _
        ).Select
   Sheets("Raw").Range("AW1").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Sheets("Raw").Range("AG23").Select

    Sheets("Raw").Cells.Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 9.71
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 13.71
    Sheets("Raw").Range("D14").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you seen this poast before? If not have a look before doing anymore coding... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .Select on cells then the sheet of those cells must be active. Add this on the first line:

```
Sheets("Raw").Activate
```

Comment: Using `.Select` and `.Activate` is frowned upon and also makes any code messy, unreadable and very slow... Suggest OP reads my link as this will have many benefits now and in the future

Comment: it works thanks! but ill try to change according to the link.